# Alternatives to global array or "array" of '#define's?

Tags: c, arrays, c-preprocessor

My current code uses some `#define`s to have all the constants in a single `.h` file.

A new modification to the program specification is coming this way and this will require some of the constants to be case-dependant, i.e. a variable will set the case (of 3 possible) and according to it the appropriate value must be used for some of these constants, e.g:

```
#define CONSTANT1 1.0F
#define CONSTANT2 2.0F

float foo(float var)
{
    return (CONSTANT1 + CONSTANT2*var);
}
```

I can currently think of approaching this problem in 2 ways:

Way1- have a `#define` for each of the possible values, implement a `switch-case` with 3 copies of the code and in each use the corresponding constant

```
#define CONSTANT1_a 1.0F
#define CONSTANT2_a 2.0F

#define CONSTANT1_b 2.0F
#define CONSTANT2_b 3.0F

#define CONSTANT1_c 3.0F
#define CONSTANT2_c 4.0F

switch(var_case)
{
case 0:
     float foo(float var)
     {
         return (CONSTANT1_a + CONSTANT2_a*var);
     }
case 1:
     float foo(float var)
     {
         return (CONSTANT1_b + CONSTANT2_b*var);
     }
case 2:
     float foo(float var)
     {
         return (CONSTANT1_c + CONSTANT2_c*var);
     }
}
```

Way2- have the constants no more as `#define`s, but as global arrays defined at the top of the corresponding file and have a single implementation of the code with the "case" that selects the position in the array

```
float CONSTANT1 [] = {1.0F,2.0F,3.0F};
float CONSTANT2 [] = {2.0F,3.0F,4.0F};

float foo(float var)
{
    return (CONSTANT1[var_case] + CONSTANT2[var_case]*var);
}
```

I tend towards the second solution, as it seems more maintanable and clean, but the use of global arrays does not sound great. Is there an alternative? Is there a way to have a `#define` containing an array? (or something equivalent)

**EDIT:**
my apologies for not mentioning before.
The code must be C89 (ANSI C).

Comment: Please add a relevant coding example to each one of the approaches that you have in mind. It is hard to follow your exact intentions for each case.

Comment: Compound literal : `#define ARRAY ((const char *[]){ "ZERO", "ONE", "TWO", "THREE"})`

Comment: It's a runtime-switch?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, I was just starting to think of writing an answer with this. Only thing that you are missing, I think is to have the type `const`-qualified, `(char const*const[]){ ... }`, this leaves the compiler more freedom.

Comment: @JensGustedt yes, i forget `const`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I have no experience with those, could you expand in an answer, please?

Comment: Compound literal has been supported since  C99. So this can not be done with C89. Examples of the use : `#define CONSTANT1 ((const float[]){1.0F,2.0F,3.0F})` ... `CONSTANT1[var_case]`. Note : life scope is local scope.

Comment: You can declare those arrays local within the function (or `static` local if you want to avoid the re-initialization every time the function is called).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY `this can not be done with C89` and that's why. I have to work with ANSI C.

Comment: @barakmanos can you make an answer out of it?

Comment: use a sequence in the .h file that looks at a defined value to select which of the three sets of values to use.  Add a -dcontrolValue=1 or 2 or 3 when compiling.  (best to use a make file because the make file can set a default value if the -d... has not been defined on the invokation line of the make.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using global arrays for constants is fine. Your preprocessor constants were already global in the first place.
Just add `const` and you are done.

**constants.c**

```
const float CONSTANT1 [] = {1.0F,2.0F,3.0F};
const float CONSTANT2 [] = {2.0F,3.0F,4.0F};
```

**constants.h**

```
extern const float CONSTANT1 [];
extern const float CONSTANT2 [];
```

Or, if you want to make arrays private to your current compilation unit, add `static`.

```
static const float CONSTANT1 [] = {1.0F,2.0F,3.0F};
```

Comment: "*... arrays private to your current compilation unit, add static*" and add them to the `.c` file they shall be private to.

Comment: if they are private to one compilation unit I can skip the `extern` lines in the `.h` file, right?

Comment: @Federico Yes, no need for header.

Answer (score -3):

I can't verify this right now, but this might work: A #define Macro can be an array, or pretty much anything. Do it like this:

```
#define CONSTANTS int temp[]={1,2,3,4};
//.. Later..
int x = (CONSTANTS)[2];
```

All a #define does is say to the compiler: before you compile this, replace every instance in the code of the defined constant ( in this case CONSTANTS) with whatever comes after (in this case "temp[]={1,2,3,4}"). So the above code would be compiled as

```
int x = (temp[]={1,2,3,4})[2];
```

This becomes unreliable though, because temp would have to be a reserved variable name within that scope. I recommend using the switch or a standin variable plus a couple of ternary conditionals for a one-liner.

Comment: This won't compile, as after pre-prcoessing the code would look like: `int x = (int temp[]={1,2,3,4};)[2];`. If your intention was to use *compound literals* it should have been: `#define CONSTANTS ((const int[]){1, 2, 3, 4})`, which however wouldn't compile either as *compound literals* are not available under C89.